# object is not a function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In my jquery, I am getting error

> `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`

---

Here is the code:

```
var localValues = new Array('txtA', 'txtB', 'txtC');
for (var intCount = 0; intCount < localValues.length; intCount++) {
    var control = $('#' + localValues(intCount));  /* ERROR */
    validationOfControls(control);
}   

function validationOfControls(control) {
  // code here
}
```

It seems to be silly mistake, but I cant figure it out..

Can you please explain what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace:

```
localValues(intCount)
```

With:

```
localValues[intCount]
```

The round brackets `()` are used for function execution. Square brackets `[]` are used for array/object access.

Comment: Small things like this are easy to miss :-P